# What does `.prose ol[type="A" s] ` the last `s` mean in CSS?

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I was studying tailwind CSS typography plugin's output CSS code and found out this

https://unpkg.com/@tailwindcss/typography@0.4.1/dist/typography.css

On line 33

```css
.prose ol[type="A" s] {
  --list-counter-style: upper-alpha;
}

.prose ol[type="a" s] {
  --list-counter-style: lower-alpha;
}
```

There is this little `s` at last, what does that mean?

And if I change my VSCode syntax to SCSS, it outputs an error

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors:

> Adding an s (or S) before the closing bracket causes the value to be compared case-sensitively (for characters within the ASCII range).

This is an experimental setting. MDN lists the only browser that implements it as being Firefox.

So it seems as though you aren't going to be able to change styling depending on whether the list is set as having upper or lower case markers (assumably they want to match that in some way) on most browsers as without the little s both A and a will match.